# Bootstrap Carousel to display text

Tags: php, carousel

I want to display long notes on bootstrap carousel. the notes will be fetched from mySql database. Since the notes are long, i need to split them using number of words then display them in the carousel slides. the problems is that am not able to display the splitted text in different slides. the following is what i have done:

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Lecture</div>

        <!-- Slider News by Carousel -->
        <div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
            <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                <?php
                include "config/koneksi.php";
                $query = "select notes from notes where Note_ID = 34";
                $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $w = $row['notes'];
                    $arr2 = str_split($w, 500);
                }

                //var_dump($arr2);
                $max = sizeof($arr2);

                $slides = '';
                $Indicators = '';
                $counter = 0;

                ?>
            </ol>
            <div class='carousel-inner'>
                <?php

                for ($x = 0; $x <= $max; $x++) {

                    if ($x == 0) {
                        echo "<div class='item active'>";
                        echo $arr2[$x]++;
                        echo "</div>";

                    } else { 

                        echo "<div class='item'>";

                        if (!isset($arr2[$x])) {
                            $arr2[$x] = 0;
                        }
                        echo $arr2[$x]++;
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }

                echo "</div>";
                echo "<a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='prev'>‹</a>";
                echo "<a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='next'>&rsaquo;</a>";

                echo "</div>";

                echo "<!-- End Slider Caraousel-->";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeGH9.png)

Comment: `str_split ()` is a barbaric function for this purpose.  Wouldn't you rather use something that would truncate after whole words?  Your method is sure to mangle your text, right?

Comment: What is the current result?  Can we see a screenshot?  I think this will help us to understand your desired result.

Comment: Yes the text are mangle. i have edited the post and attached the result. thank you

Comment: I assume you have a variable number of photos and a variable amount of text to distribute evenly.  Then you have to consider available space on the myriad of device screen sizes.  Can this issue possibly be solved well?  I think you will need to create some firm boundaries in your design before doing the coding.